# How to send JSON encoded PHP array to datatables on same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, datatable

Have a simple question here but am new to datatables so forgive my ignorance: I have a query of rows that I placed in an array and then encoded it in JSON format, how can I send this array to datatables in order to populate each row? I've looked at other threads but they are using ajax to externally reference the script whereas mine is located on the same page (not sure if that makes a difference). My script looks like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['post_id'])){
    $in = $_POST['post_id'];
}
$data = array();
foreach ($in as $id){
    $query = $link->prepare("SELECT provider_num, provider_name, 233_net_charity_care, 291_cost_of_non_mcr_bad_debts, 301_cost_of_uncomp_care 
                            FROM `s10`
                            WHERE `id` = :id");
    $query->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
    $results = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $data[] = $results;
}
json_encode($data);
?>
```

Where post_id is the initial array of id values submitted to the page from the previous form, for simplicity's sake lets say that I only have one row submitted this time.

The JSON output looks like this

`[{"provider_num":"140124","provider_name":"JOHN H. STROGER JR. HOSP OF COOK CTY","233_net_charity_care":"163307737","291_cost_of_non_mcr_bad_debts":"181677291","301_cost_of_uncomp_care":"344985028"}]`

In what way do I then initialize datatables to receive this data

So far I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "ajax": "",                      <== What goes here?
        "columns": [
            { "data": "provider_num" },
            { "data": "provider_name" },
            { "data": "233_net_charity_care" },
            { "data": "291_cost_of_non_mcr_bad_debts" },
            { "data": "301_cost_of_uncomp_care" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Any insight would be great, I'm pretty new to jquery in general so apologies if this is an easy question. I tried to read the documentation but had trouble relating to it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `json_encode(data)` should be `echo json-encode(data)`.

Comment: so in that case, just make the script external and then reference it in the ajax field in datatables? Currently it's on the same page and I wouldn't want it to echo on that page

Comment: `@Barmar`, you're making me laugh, with that comment. `ajax:` is where the datatable gets external JSON data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is, if your frontend script and server script(php) is in the same page, you don't need to use ajax.

you can simply set the data like this after your php script

```
var tableData = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
```

Then in datatable initialize method, use this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "aaData": tableData,                               
        "aoColumns": [
            { "data": "provider_num" },
            { "data": "provider_name" },
            { "data": "233_net_charity_care" },
            { "data": "291_cost_of_non_mcr_bad_debts" },
            { "data": "301_cost_of_uncomp_care" }
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: Quote on last `aoColumns` Array `title` property missing.

Comment: @Sohel I used your code, but im getting 'requested parameter '0' for row '0'. Not sure what this means...all I have is a skeleton of a table  `<table id="compTab" class="table">
        <thead>
            
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            
        </tbody>
    </table>`

To initialize onto and then I placed `var tableData = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;` right after document.ready

Comment: Replacing "title" with "data" fixed it. If you change your markup I'll go ahead and mark it correct. Thanks for the help mate.

Comment: @Habitat, done. Probably a different version or I missed something. Thanks anyway.